# Linq with case condition within the same table and count from other table in where condition

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I am trying to write a linq query with the following situations. I am trying to get Guids where there are no message sent.

I have 3 table

TableTarget

`TargetGuid |FrequencyID
1234       |1
0987       |2`

Table Frequency 

`FrequencyID|FrequencyTypeID |Time1|Time2
1          |2               |8 AM  | 12 PM
2          |1               |2 PM  |null`

TableSentHistory

This table is updated after target is sent.

`TargetGuid|SentTime
1234       |2019-04-04 08:05:06
1234       |2019-04-04 12:05:06
0987       |2019-04-04 02:05:06`

Now I want to pull the data where time1 or time2 > current time and count from the Tablesenthistory for todays date should be less than 2 if the frequency is 1 in the frequency table and count <3 if the frequency is 2 in the frequency table.
Right now I am pulling all the data from the Target and frequency table and running in memory operation. This is causing me performance issue because I am pulling all the guids and checking with if conditions.

Is there a way to Get only the ones which are not sent today by checking the sent history.

I am also facing issue with race condition while running in multiple servers.
This is my linq query.

```
     var targets = (from dt in _context.Target
                              join df in context.Frequency on dt.FrequencyId equals df.FrequencyId                                  
                              where df.Time1.TimeOfDay < DateTime.UtcNow.TimeOfDay
                                    || (df.Time2.TimeOfDay < DateTime.UtcNow.TimeOfDay
                                        && df.Time2 != System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.MinValue.Value.ToUniversalTime())
                              select new Processing
                              {
                                 TargetGuid = dt.TargetGUID,
                                  Time1 = df.Time1,
                                  Time2 = df.Time2,
                                  FrequencyType = (FrequencyType)df.FrequencyTypeId
                              }).ToList();
```

I have also tried to add the third table join but not able to get the count and case wise comparison.

I tried this after the solution posted but I am getting this error. 
Nullable object must have a value.

```
var history = (from ds in context.ServiceHistory
                           where ds.SentTime.Date == DateTime.UtcNow.Date
                           group ds by ds.TargetGuid into grp
                           select new
                           {
                               TargetGuid = grp.Key,
                               Count = grp.Count()
                           }).ToList();

            var Targets = (
                            from dt in context.Target
                            join df in context.Frequency
                            on dt.FrequencyId equals df.FrequencyId
                            join h in history on dt.TargetGUID equals h.TargetGuid into hist
                            from h in hist.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            where df.Time1.TimeOfDay < DateTime.UtcNow.TimeOfDay
                                                    || (df.Time2.TimeOfDay < DateTime.UtcNow.TimeOfDay
                                                        && df.Time2 != System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.MinValue.Value.ToUniversalTime())                                
                            && h.Count < (df.FrequencyTypeId == (int)FrequencyType.Daily ? 2 : 3)
                            select new
                            {
                                dt.TargetGUID,
                                df.FrequencyTypeId
                            }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var targets = (
    from dt in _context.Target
    join df in context.Frequency 
    on dt.FrequencyId equals df.FrequencyId                                  
    where df.Time1.TimeOfDay < DateTime.UtcNow.TimeOfDay
    || (df.Time2 != null && df.Time2.TimeOfDay < DateTime.UtcNow.TimeOfDay)
    join h in context.SentHistory.Where(hh => hh.SentTime < DateTime.UtcNow.Date)
    on dt.TargetGuid equals h.TargetGuid into history
    where history.Count() < (df.Time2 == null ? 2 : 3)
    select new Processing {
        TargetGuid = dt.TargetGUID,
        Time1 = df.Time1,
        Time2 = df.Time2,
        FrequencyType = (FrequencyType)df.FrequencyTypeId
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks @pakeha_by. I ended up using your logic with some change but I am getting nullable object must have a value error when putting the left join.